# Get a single value from query

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I want to get a rentalId value from this query. Then I tried like this, but I have some error. Last coding I have got error like

> 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.CurrentRow.get' returns null

Code:

```
public int RentalId { get; set; }

String query2 = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Rental ORDER BY RentalId DESC";
ds = new DataSet();
da = new SqlDataAdapter(query2, con);
da.Fill(ds);
builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
dgvInUse.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];          
dgvInUse.Rows[0].Selected = true;

// I don't know how to extract RentalId
RentalId = Convert.ToInt32(dgvInUse.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
```

Comment: You should analyze the issue step by step, so you can locate where the problem is. I would recommend to show the content of the field RentalId using a MessageBox or any Debug output just after executing the query to ensure that this works fine. In case this works fine, then you can proceed debuging the following code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentrow):

> To change the current row, you must set the CurrentCell property to a
>   cell in the desired row.

Marking a row as selected doesn't make it current (you can have several selected rows, but the current row must be only one).

**Edit:**

```
        if (dgvInUse.Rows.Count > 0 && dgvInUse.Rows[0].Cells.Count > 0 && dgvInUse.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value != null)
            RentalId = Convert.ToInt32(dgvInUse.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value);
        else
            throw new Exception("Cannot get RentalId"); // or other action
```

Comment: RentalId = Convert.ToInt32(dgvInUse.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString()); will get value as 'rentalId', but get value is '0'. In dgvInUse, I selected only 1 value. Would you give me for example coding? Thanks.

Comment: `RentalId = Convert.ToInt32(dgvInUse.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString());` Of course, you need to perform a check before - it may happens, your query doesn't return any row. Additionally, I can advice to specify columns in SQL query, like `"SELECT TOP 1 RentalId, other fields... FROM Rental ORDER BY RentalId DESC"`

Comment: Thank you. It solved from change 'currentRow' to 'Rows'. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! :) Please inspect my edits too - I added some checks for case if no records there are in query results.